# Excel VBA - adding Bold text to statement

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code, and I need to make the inserted text bold. How do I add this to my statement (can't figure out the syntax)? Thanks!

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim addme As Long
    Set ws = Worksheets("Projects")
    addme = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

' Insert data from UserForm into Columns 2 & 3
    With ws
        ws.Cells(addme, 2).value = Me.SuperProject1.value 'the number 2 here represents the Column B
        ws.Cells(addme, 3).value = Me.SProjectName1.value 'the number 3 represents Column C
    End With
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
With ws
    .Cells(addme, 2).value = Me.SuperProject1.value 
    .Cells(addme, 3).value = Me.SProjectName1.value
    .Cells(addme, 2).Resize(1, 2).Font.Bold = True  
End With
```